# c# string loop without specific number of loops

Tags: c#

I have problem with looping code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = Console.ReadLine();
            TextInfo ti = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
            Console.WriteLine(ti.ToTitleCase(text).Replace(" ", string.Empty));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And maybe it's wrote like it shouldn't be because I can't find a way to fix it. To be specific I want this program to enter sentence in multiple lines of unknown number, it delete all white space and change every word first letter to upper case. So for example the enter data is:

> I wanna ride bicycle,
>
> but Rick say skateboard is better.

And output is:

> IWannaRideBicycle,
>
> ButRickSaySkateboardIsBetter.

The program can't have user interface so I think about while and making a list of strings but the problem for me will be still a way to loop it. I found a solution in C++ that they use "while ( getline (cin, text){}" but I think it's not useful in C#.

Comment: There's no loop there. See that code in `Main`? Put it in a loop. That's where loops come from: You. You are where loops come from. The Loop Man. Loopmeister. Looparooney. But seriously, look up "console input while loop c#" or something on Google, you'll see plenty of code you can steal.

Comment: While loops do indeed exist in C#.

Comment: I'm wondering if OP knows what a loop is.

Comment: yet another `Horrible Question` that shows major lack of effort definitely downvoting and voting to close

Comment: I'm glad you found this question worth to answer even if u think it's so stupid. I could write some kind of loop and say its not working and why. My problem was how to exit a loop. I'm also glad someone posted answer, it wasn't 100% working but it helped me how to do it. Btw sorry for English, I work to improve it.

Comment: Where is the loop? What is the question?

Comment: Nevermind, if u wanna loop here u have, While(true){ string text = Console.ReadLine(); TextInfo ti = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo; Console.WriteLine(ti.ToTitleCase(text).Replace(" ", string.Empty)); } also in my first post I wrote in c++ I can use getline what doesn't exist in c# and have no replacement. The question is already answered and I wanted just to know how to break loop when i don't know how many lines of code will be wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while loop should do the trick. [Console.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) returns null if no more lines are available.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      List<string> converted = new List<string>();

      while (true)   // forever
      {
          string text = Console.ReadLine();

          if (text == null)
          {
              break;    // no more lines available - break out of loop.
          }

          // Convert to capitals
          TextInfo ti = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;

          string convertedText = ti.ToTitleCase(text).Replace(" ", "");

          converted.Add(convertedText);
      }

      // Now display the converted lines
      foreach (string text in converted)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(text);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = Console.ReadLine();
while(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
{
    TextInfo ti = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
    Console.WriteLine(ti.ToTitleCase(text).Replace(" ", string.Empty));
    text = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I think this may be a suitable solution. It will read input from the console until the user simply hits 'Enter' and sends you an empty string. I don't know that there is a more dynamic way to achieve what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your input is.

If its an `IEnumerable<string>` then simply use `foreach`:

```
var lines = ... //some IEnumerable<string>

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    //do your thing
}
```

This will keep on looping as long as there is one more line to enumerate in `lines`. It can, in theory, keep on going forever.

If your input is a `Stream` then build a `StreamReader` around it and basically do the same (but with more plumbing):

```
using (var inputStream = ...// some stream)
using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
{
     var line = reader.ReadLine();

     while (line != null)
     {
          //do your thing
          line = reader.ReadLine();
     }
}
```

This again will loop as long as the input stream can produce a new line.